# How to install libXt and libXrender on 64bit?

Tags: laravel

i installed libXt using yum but appear error [Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
You need to be root to perform this command.]

```
[vagrant@localhost html]$ yum install libXt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

Could you help me how to install libXt and  libXrender?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be root as stated in error message, so the fix is just as simple as that:

`sudo yum install libXt`

Please note that some hosting providers will not allow you to do that.

If that's the case you should upgrade your account or move to different hosting provider.

Comment: i run the console file using php artisan,appear file not found error. Now i use sudo yum install LibXt using vagrant,run again console but not change error message.Error is  >> The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
  stderr: "/home/vagrant/www/html/lib/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf: error while
  loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file:
  No such file or directory

Comment: i install $ sudo yum install libXrender and run console.change error message. whatever thank so much your suggestion.

Comment: @KhineThu I suppose you are running vagrant remotely. You need to log in/ ssh to this instance to make any changes (especially marked obove). You can consider this as completely other system running in your environment.... On the other hand you need to remember that your changes willl most probably get overwritten by new versions of that package. So my best suggestions here are to move hese modifications to tests and don't change initial package. That of course is valid if that is your workflow....

Comment: @KhineThu Please check how you can login into underlying vagrant  OS...And then issue commands suggested before...

Comment: @Bart Thank you. This installed 64-bit libXt in AWS EC2 ..